# Subtract time in php. Strange results

Tags: php, time

```
echo date('H:i', time()); // 10:15    
echo date('H:i', strtotime($this->deadline)); // 10:05
$delay = time() - strtotime($this->deadline);
echo date('H:i', $delay); // 02:10
```

Why `delay` is 2 hours 10 min instead of 10 min?

I assume it has something to do with timezone. Now it's Europe/Helsinki. But how can I get just an absolute difference between two timestamps?

**EDIT**

```
echo time(); // 1339745334
echo strtotime($this->deadline); // 1339657500
```

Comment: Also post the timestamp value that you get from time() and strtotime($this->deadline).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$delay is not actually a proper timestamp. It's just the difference between two timestamps, which could be as low as 1. mktime() function could be useful here.

Comment: I don't understand why people always try to date the result of a substraction between 2 timestamps... time1 - time2 = numberOfSeconds... if you want that in mins or hours /60, /3600

Comment: How I would use mktime() here?

Comment: @sevenWonders: here's an example if you don't want to do it from scratch: http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/php-calculate-real-differences-between-two-dates-or-timestamps/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
date_diff($time_start, $time_ends);

function date_diff($d1, $d2){
        $d1 = (is_string($d1) ? strtotime($d1) : $d1);
        $d2 = (is_string($d2) ? strtotime($d2) : $d2);
        $diff_secs = abs($d1 - $d2);
        $base_year = min(date("Y", $d1), date("Y", $d2));
        $diff = mktime(0, 0, $diff_secs, 1, 1, $base_year);
        return array(
            "years" => date("Y", $diff) - $base_year,
            "months_total" => (date("Y", $diff) - $base_year) * 12 + date("n", $diff) - 1,
            "months" => date("n", $diff) - 1,
            "days_total" => floor($diff_secs / (3600 * 24)),
            "days" => date("j", $diff) - 1,
            "hours_total" => floor($diff_secs / 3600),
            "hours" => date("G", $diff),
            "minutes_total" => floor($diff_secs / 60),
            "minutes" => (int) date("i", $diff),
            "seconds_total" => $diff_secs,
            "seconds" => (int) date("s", $diff)
        );
    }
```

Comment: $time_ends is a $this->deadline and $time_start is a current time

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the real time you will need to format the time accourding to the difference. Here an example function which you can extend as you wish:

```
function time_diff($format,$seperator,$delay){

    $days = floor($delay/86400);
    $hours = floor(($delay%86400)/3600);
    $mins = floor(($delay%3600)/60);
    $secs = floor(($delay%60));

    $format = explode($seperator,$format);
    $return = "";

    foreach($format as $value){

        if(strlen($return) > 0){
            $return .= $seperator;
        }

        switch($value){
            case 'H':{
                $return .= $hours;
                break;
            }
            case 'i':{
                $return .= $mins;
                break;
            }
            case 'z':{
                $return .= $days;
                break;
            }
            case 's':{
                $return .= $secs;
                break;
            }
        }

        return $return;                    
    }
```

Usage: `function_time_diff("H:i",':',$delay)` => Your delay formatted.